# Passing javascript loop value to Laravel Controller

Tags: javascript, laravel

I want to get values from multiple select and pass them to Laravel controller.

**Getting all values from multiple select:**

```
<script>
    function redirect() {
        $("#sbtwo > option").each(function() {
            if(document.getElementById("report1").checked == true)
                window.open (+this.value+"/report1", 'w1');
        });
    }
</script>
```

**I want to get `+this.value+` and pass it to Laravel controller.**

```
<form action="/teachers/printreports" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="checkbox" name="report1[]"  id="report1"> Basic Data</div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary " value="Print" >
</form>
```

How to store javascript `+this.value+` in to form element `name= report1[]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multi-select with checkbox

In blade file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/multiple-select@1.3.1/dist/multiple-select.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/multiple-select@1.3.1/dist/multiple-select.min.js"></script>


<form action="/teachers/printreports" method="POST">
    @csrf

    <select name="reports[]" id="select" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">Report-1</option>
        <option value="2">Report-2</option>
        <option value="3">Report-3</option>
        <option value="4">Report-4</option>
        <option value="5">Report-5</option>
        <option value="6">Report-6</option>
        <option value="7">Report-7</option>
        <option value="8">Report-8</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary " value="Print" >
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(function () {
            $('.select').multipleSelect({
                width: 500
            })
        })
    });            
</script>
```

In Controller:

```
public function yourFunction(Request $request){
    $post = $request->all();

    // dump your selected reports
    dd($post);
}
```

Result:

```
array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "WXs56rP5fWWw3D4B1H8I1wibT23Dko2AfFPmFRiZ"
  "reports" => array:5 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
    2 => "4"
    3 => "6"
    4 => "7"
  ]
]
```